# Are there any free .NET OCR libraries that will perform OCR on an application window directly?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, screen-scraping, ocr

I am looking for a free .NET OCR library that will be able to do OCR on a given application window or even a image in memory (I can take a snapshot of the application window myself).

I have looked at [tessnet2](http://pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2) and [MODI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging) but both require an image located on disk.

I need to use OCR because the application I am trying to write a script for does some wacky stuff that cannot be read using windows API and I need to scrape data from the screen.  I have tested both of [tessnet2](http://pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2) and [MODI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging) and they both can read the text mostly but because this has to run in an enviroment that will not be able to write to disk, I need it to be able to read directly from the applciation window or some type of memory stream.

I am thinking OCR is my only soution but there could be other methods that I am not thinking of.

Suggestions?

**Edit based on comments:** Environment is a C# .NET windows application with no disk access.  It's an application that has code compiled and executed on the fly and this code is running in a context that should not need any resources other than memory.

Comment: Why can't you write to disk? What kind of environment?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen just assume I can't.  It's a long story that I would rather not explain ;)

Comment: No, I don't doubt you can't, but perhaps details about the environment you're in can give people extra information that can help give you better answers? For instance, for all I know you're in Silverlight...

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen good point.  I have added some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>As I can see from the Tessnet page example the library requires a Bitmap to be passed in so what if you create it with [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) Method ?</del>

You can create Bitmap object with this constructor: [Bitmap Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx)

Comment: I am in the process of looking into this.