# OCR library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [OCR for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870280/ocr-for-net)
>   [OCR in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591574/ocr-in-net)

is there any good .NET OCR library? I'm interested in both free and non-free libraries.

Answer (score 1):

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is a very good Apache 2.0 licensed OCR engine. I have used it from C++ and had very good results. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328/ocr-with-the-tesseract-interface/127405#127405) recommends a .NET wrapper called [Tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870280/ocr-for-net) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850758/are-there-any-free-net-ocr-libraries-that-will-perform-ocr-on-an-application-win) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641173/i-need-a-good-ocr) on StackOverflow; Tessnet seems a popular choice.

Comment: There is also a good commercial version based on the tesseract - [tesseract.net sdk](http://tesseract.patagames.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ABBYY FineCapture](http://finereader.abbyy.com/) in the past and I like it quite a bit.  This is not free though, but ABBYY also offers some cool products that handle stuff like ICR (hand writing OCR).

It offers some .NET libraries but, most of the work I did with it was within the product itself.  You would have to do a little research to see if they will fit your needs.